# Symfony2 Amazon SES SMTP Mail Setup

Tags: symfony, smtp, email, amazon-ses

I have a Symfony2 application that needs to use Amazon SES to send mails. I need to set this up using SMTP. For some reason my Symfony2 app has just not been able to send mails since I have put it live on the instance. It works perfectly on my local server and sends mail using gmail but on the live server niether gmail not Amazon SES works. My configurations are:

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       SMTPHOST
mailer_encryption: tls
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_user:       SMTPUSER
mailer_password:   SMTPPASS
mailer_port:       465
```

I have taken all three things SMTPHOST, SMTPUSER and SMTPPASS from the SES console online. But still the mails don't seem to go. I really don't want to setup a seperate mail server. I use Symfony2's pre-integrated Swiftmailer Library for sending all the email and so do the 3rd party bundles.

I have no idea how to do this since this is the first time I'm using AWS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work because you have chosen port 465. Use 587. Lengthy explanation is here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

Check you have this in app/config/config.yml:

```
# app/config/config.yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
```

In my case the encryption line was missing. And clear your cache afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To send e-mails through AWS SES you need to activate the account. When you start, your AWS SES account is in the [sandbox](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html), so you need to file an issue to Amazon asking them to fully activate your account.

One of the requirements is that you can [manage bounces and complaints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/best-practices-bounces-complaints.html).

To do this with Symfony you can use the AWS SES Monitor bundle that can setup for you all the stuff needed to send e-mails through AWS SES.

it also has a plugin for SwiftMailer to make you abel to filter out email addresses that have bounces or complaints, so you can maintain your SES account's health.